# Application.StartupPath contains spaces

Tags: c#

In a previous question ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607151/unable-to-access-jar-file)), a solution was given so I know now where the problem is.
But now I have no idea how to solve it...

What if my Application.StartupPath contains spaces? How should I quote them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a double quote be a part of a string using [escape characters](http://blogs.msdn.com/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/88415.aspx) (just put a backslash in front of the quote).

From your previous question, here's how you could enclose the entire path to your *.jar file in double quotes:

```
var pathJava = "\""+ Application.StartupPath + "\\pathToJavaApp\\javaApp.jar" + "\"";
```

Comment: So it is just quoting the whole line? I was searching it more complicated then that.

Comment: or use @ character @"\somepath\"

Comment: Better simple and easy to solve than complicated and obscure :)