# File path failing when installing the finished program

Tags: c#, directory, exe, filepath

I have a little problem:  I am using some files for view reports when my program is running, I've created the setup .exe file and works fine because in the code has a absolute path that like this:

```
        ReportDocument crystalReport = new ReportDocument();
        crystalReport.Load("C:\\Program Files\\Electrolytic Capacitor Designer\\Crystal Reports\\SpecSheet.rpt");
```

When I install the program on another computer and I choose this path for installation everything is OK, but obviously if i choose another one, the program prompts me an exception because couldn't find the file.....

Is there a method or something like that could help me on resolve this?

Comment: What is the error? Also, is the rpt file being dropped in the install location?

Comment: Unhandled exception has occurred in your application.  If you click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue.  If you click quit the application will close immediately.

Load Report Failed



I dont know i think the program cannot find this files....

Answer (score 1):

If your path has spaces, you will need to encapsulate the path in double quotes quotes. You may need to put a double quote before StartupPath and after .rpt

Comment: but the Application.StartupPath is a method that let you get this path right?, i think this cannot be a String because is not going to be detected, am I right?

Comment: It is not a matter of getting the path right... If I am right, it may be due to spaces in the directory name that is causing it to not find your file. So, if you explicitly set your directory path to have a starting double quote and an ending double quote, that may help the program to process the file path and filename correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607433/application-startuppath-contains-spaces

Comment: ok, I tried it on and nothing happened :/ the same error is still prompting, dang!!

Answer (score 0):

Try running the exe as Administrator. If your installer is installing it to the Program Files folder you'll have file permission issues.

If this is the problem (or even if it's not), consider using a different folder such as the My Documents folder instead of the executable path for storing files.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
```

Comment: aaa ok but if it is right to put this files inside the Debug folder of the project?

Comment: This is the massage that I get:

When i try to open a txt file it promtps me this massage:

Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click continue the application will ignore this error and attempt to continue. If you click quit the application will close immediately.

Could not find a part of the path C:/Documents and Settings/100002219/Desktop/Reports/DLFiles

Comment: Probably wouldn't hurt to use a try/catch block around placed you're doing file IO. I don't know if I understand the problem... Why is it looking in your desktop for files?