# Reading jar stream in c# from the console

Tags: c#, java, process

i found some code online to run my jar (which outputs to the console either true or false) from c# and read it in. On my development machine the following code works fine

```
    private bool hasInformation(String value)
    {
        try
        {

            using (Process p = new Process())
            {
                p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("java", @" -jar myJarName.jar " + value);
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.Start();
                String availableOrNot = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                p.WaitForExit();
                //Trace.WriteLine("data = " + s);

                availableOrNot = availableOrNot.Trim();
                if (availableOrNot.Equals("true"))
                {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            LogWriter.writeToLogFile(e);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The problem is that on my testing machine the code returns just an empty string as if its throwing an exception before it can execute.

I have no idea what else to check for as the jar file runs fine in the command line window when i manually do it and no exception is being thrown (well its not being caught at least) . All that happens is that i get an empty string, where as on my development machine i get a true or false answer.

Hopefully someone might have some ideas of what might be going wrong so that i can investigate as i am really stuck.

Thanks

Edit : After redirecting the error message so i can read that from the stream i get the error

> Unable to access jarfile myJarName.jar\r\n"

Comment: Are you perhaps executing the code differently on the test machine?  E.g. perhaps calling it from an ASP.Net application as opposed to a Windows application on your dev machine?  Any user privilege differences (is the code running under the same user when you do a manual test and when you run the code)?

Comment: The code is running under the same user yes, but there is a slightly different setup. Would spawning a process get blocked then?

Comment: Well, there definitely seems to be some difference in the setup, which is causing the problem.  Without knowing the exact details it's difficult to guess, so I'm just trying to get you to think along those lines.  If code-level debugging is not helping, I would suggest getting the SysInternals suite, and using Process Monitor / Process Explorer to see what actually happens on an OS level when these calls are being made.  Is the Java app starting, etc.

Comment: is it possible then that the code cant run if i dont have local admin?

Comment: The code itself to start a process should work fine without local admin rights, but perhaps the Java app requires it for whatever it's trying to do.  It should be easy enough to test this; try to make your environments identical, hopefully at that point it will start working on your test environment.  At that point it should be easy enough to keep re-testing while changing back the environment to how it is now; when it stops working, your last change is the reason for it.

Comment: My java app shouldnt be an issue i am sure of it. If it runs in the cobsole window manually then it should work within the programme? i am wondering if this might be the reason http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607151/unable-to-access-jar-file ?

Comment: OK, the exception info you posted seems to suggest either the working directory or classpath is wrong.  I've posted an answer below with suggested solutions, as have others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the new info you posted, it's probably either the working directory or the CLASSPATH environment variable that's wrong.

Check the working directory to see if it's what you expect (I'm guessing it should be the same as that JAR file's directory), or set it:

```
p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\path to my JAR file";
```

Alternatively, set the CLASSPATH:

```
p.StartInfo.EnvironmentVariables["CLASSPATH"] = "C:\\.....";
```

Comment: the working directory was not set, which i dont understand, at all. why would this happen? For now i put it in a folder in the c drive called a just to test, i guess i will have to escape a hard coded path - but what about when it gets installed, do i just preempt the path

Comment: Depending on the other parameters you specify on the ProcessStartInfo object, .Net will use different logic to determine the path where it's going to be working.  The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.workingdirectory.aspx) on the topic might give some insight, although at first glance it doesn't seem obvious why you were having issues even though UseShellExecute was set to false.  In either case, it's probably best to be specific; perhaps store the path in the app.config to allow for configurability during / after deployment?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of your problem appears to be that your `CLASSPATH` environment variable is set differently on the two machines. In one case it includes `myJarName.jar` and in the other it doesn't.

Comment: classpath for machine one - `.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip` and for machine 2 `.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.6.0_05\lib\ext\QTJava.zip`

Comment: Are you sure that in both cases your jar file is in the working directory of your process?

Comment: it appears the second machine is pointing to the QTJava.zip yet there is no such thing in that folder. Yes the jar file is always in the working directory (set to copy always)

Comment: As far as the problem you asked about goes, this should not matter. It's the location of `myJarName.jar` that does.

Comment: Ok, well the project is set to copy the jar to the directory always. I created a new jar file that just prints hello to the console, imported this in to my application and it worked. The thing is, i can manually run my jar file from the terminal so it should therfore work in my application? or is that an assumption i shouldnt be making!

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct your code, to allow read the output. You have to initialize RedirectStandardOutput. Example,

```
        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(commandName, commandArgumentsForLogging);
        processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processInfo.ErrorDialog = false;

        var p = new Process { StartInfo = processInfo };
```

Comment: OP is saying that "no exception is being thrown "

Comment: Yes, i would like to confirm, the code when debugging doesnt skip in to the catch block for the exception - all i get is a empty string returned. The jar file runs from the command line perfectly when typing the command in manually