# Copying file to .jar file results in an error

Tags: c#, java

I am attempting to copy a zip file to a jar file in a C# method like this:

```cs
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
start.FileName = "java.exe";
start.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\mydir\";
start.Arguments = @" -jar example.jar example.zip";
Process java = new Process();
java.StartInfo = start;
java.Start();

var stdOut = java.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
java.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine(java.ExitCode.ToString());
```

The problem is that I am receiving this error:

**Error: Unable to access jarfile example.jar**

I've confirmed that both example.jar and example.zip exist in the Working Directory and have also written a batch file that I can run and create a .jar file that is almost identical:

```
jar -cf example.jar test.zip
```

I was able to run this without issue with this code:

```
const string batchFile = @"C:\mydir\batJar.bat";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(batchFile);
```

My environment variables (Windows 7) are also set up properly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607151/unable-to-access-jar-file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing lines:

2-FileName

AND

4-Arguments

fixed my problem:

```
  ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
  start.FileName = "jar";
  start.WorkingDirectory =@"C:\myDir";
  start.Arguments = @" cf myJar.jar test.zip";**
  start.UseShellExecute = false;
  start.RedirectStandardInput = true;
  start.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

  Process java = new Process();
  java.StartInfo = start;
  java.Start();

  var stdOut = java.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
  java.WaitForExit();
  Console.WriteLine(java.ExitCode.ToString());
```

Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your batch file uses executable "jar", but your C# program uses executable "java.exe".

Try:

```
start.FileName = "jar";
```

Comment: `jar` is what creates the `.jar` file (a zip containing `.class` files). `java -jar <jar file>` is what executes the entry point defined in a `.class` file in the `.jar` file.